# Image segmentation error 999999 with NAIP in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, error-999999, image-analysis

I'm trying to do object-based image analysis on a portion of the NAIP 2016 aerial imagery for Washington (4-band, 8-bit unsigned).

**Image:** The NAIP file I'm using is accessed through a USDA server. To do this, I go into the Catalog sidebar, scroll down to GIS Servers, click "Add ArcGIS Server", and add the server URL https://gis.apfo.usda.gov/arcgis/services. The file I use is in the "NAIP" folder, called "Washington", which I drag into my Table of Contents.

**Geoprocessing:** I'm using the **Segmented Mean Shift** function on on a small portion of the NAIP image. The inputs are just the defaults, but set processing extent to the extent of a small polygon feature in a separate geodatabase. The path file for the image reads "NAIP\Washington". There is no way to link directly to the file (e.g. clicking the yellow folder next to Input Raster and navigating to the USDA server - the raster files don't appear). There are 4 bands, but the tool takes the first three by default. However, after running for a few minutes I get an Error 999999 and an incomplete output raster in grayscale.

I suspect the problem is my use of a server image. I'm not sure how to get around using a server since the entire NAIP file for Washington is 1.88 TB.

Does anyone have any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The 999999 problem is often from a problem with the original source file, in this case the server hosted NAIP file. I found that doing analysis on-the-fly in the Image Analysis window, rather than through geoprocessing, works for now. I haven't yet had to do anything more than exploration, so I'm not sure how one would get around being unable to geoprocess for more serious analyses.